# Incorrect binding for DLQ Rabbit using Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I have one simple Spring Cloud Stream application with following configuration

```
spring:
    cloud:
        stream:
            rabbit:
                bindings:
                    input:
                        consumer:
                            exchangeType: topic
                            bindingRoutingKey: service.routing
                            autoBindDlq: true
                            deadLetterExchange: service.exchange.error
                            deadLetterQueueName: service.queue.error
                            deadLetterRoutingKey: service.routing.error
                            deadLetterExchangeType: topic
                            queueNameGroupOnly: true
                            republishToDlq: true
            bindings:
                input:
                    destination: service.exchange
                    group: service.queue
                    binder: rabbit
                    consumer:
                        errorChannelEnabled: true
                        maxAttempts: 2
                        concurrency: 3
            binders:
                rabbit:
                    type: rabbit
                    environment:
                        spring:
                            rabbitmq:
                                host: ${RABBITMQ_HOST:localhost}
                                port: ${RABBITMQ_PORT:5672}
                                username: ${RABBITMQ_USERNAME:guest}
                                password: ${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD:guest}
```

Everything looks fine but the binding in DLQ is incorrect as a result DLQ is not getting any message.

#### Expected result

Exchange (service.exchange.error) **->** Routing (service.routing.error) **->** Queue (service.queue.error)

#### Actual result

Exchange (service.exchange.error) **->** Routing (service.queue) **->** Queue (service.queue.error)

Is there anyway to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When `republishToDlq` is true, we also bind with the queue name because the republisher knows nothing about partitioned destinations.

```
Binding dlqBinding = new Binding(dlq.getName(), DestinationType.QUEUE,
        dlxName, properties.getDlqDeadLetterRoutingKey() == null ? routingKey
                : properties.getDeadLetterRoutingKey(),
        null);
declareBinding(dlqName, dlqBinding);
if (properties instanceof RabbitConsumerProperties
        && ((RabbitConsumerProperties) properties).isRepublishToDlq()) {
    /*
     * Also bind with the base queue name when republishToDlq is used, which
     * does not know about partitioning
     */
    declareBinding(dlqName, new Binding(dlq.getName(), DestinationType.QUEUE,
            dlxName, baseQueueName, null));
}
```

So you should see 2 bindings - yours and the extra one.

Comment: Do I need to put this code somewhere because right now I only see one binding which I  mentioned above.

Comment: That code is in the binder's provisioner. Perhaps run it in a debugger to figure out what is going on.